# Visualizing my linear regression Model

Tags: python, linear-regression

I want to visualize the scatterplot after linear regression implementation.so i want to create a linear regression plot using Python Pandas DataFrame (pydf) and ggplot to display the scatterplot and two regression models that i used.

I have 3 prédictors (cause,wt0,dbp0) and gfr0m as a predicted value:

```
# Import numpy, pandas, and ggplot
 import numpy as np
  from pandas import *
  from ggplot import *
   # Create Python DataFrame
  cause = prepared_data.map(lambda p: (p.features[0])).collect()
   dbp0 = prepared_data.map(lambda p: (p.features[0])).collect()
   gfr0m = prepared_data.map(lambda p: (p.label)).collect()
  predA = predictionsA.select("prediction").map(lambda r: r[0]).collect()
     predB = predictionsB.select("prediction").map(lambda r: r[0]).collect()

  pydf = 
 DataFrame({'cause':cause,'wt0':wt0,'dbp0':dbp0,'gfr0m':gfr0m,'predA':predA, 
   'predB':predB})

 # Create scatter plot and two regression models (scaling exponential) using 
  ggplot
    p = ggplot(pydf, aes('cause','wt0','dbp0','gfr0m')) +
   geom_point(color='blue') +
   geom_line(pydf, aes('cause','wt0','dbp0','predA'), color='red') +
      geom_line(pydf, aes('cause','wt0','dbp0','predB'), color='green') +
    scale_x_log10() + scale_y_log10()
    display(p)
```

this code wont to execut its show me :'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'map' when i add .rdd before.map its show me as error : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 34.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 34.0 (TID 34, localhost, executor driver): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
If someone could help me in this case :)